# What if my app doesn't support iphone6?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios8, policy

I've developed/operated a game for iPhone 4 and 5 and now I'm posting an overhauled version of the game newly.

So here is my question. Will I meet a problem if the app doesn't support iPhone6?

Is there any rejection or penealty for a developer who doesn't provied supports for the new phone?

Answer (score 1):

No your app will not be rejected by Apple. Not yet that is.

Back when iPhone 5 came out with bigger screen, Apple gave us developer from Oct to Feb of next year to make our apps iPhone 5 compatible. Then March onwards all apps had to be iPhone 5 compatible otherwise they were rejected.

So short answer, your app will not be rejected now but in the coming months you should try to make it iPhone 6 and 6S screens size compatible.

Its recommended to test your apps on the actual device and Apple understands that not everyone is going to get a hold of one anytime soon except for a selected few.